# pgfplotstable: How to get 'column name' with 'pgfkeysgetvalue'

Tags: pgfplotstable

In a table

```
\pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
A  B
0  0 
-1  1 
3  2 
}\test
```

I want to set the entries of the head row `A` an `B` as column names.

I think, this can be done with 
`assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{#1 <whatever>}`

But how can I get this back with 
`\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{\Name} \Name` 
?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
A  B
0  0 
-1  1 
3  2 
}\test

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{#1 hhh},
display columns/0/.style={
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={##1 
\pgfplotstableset{columns/0/.try}%
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{\Name} \Name%
}}
},
]{\test}

\end{document}
```